# Remote MS ACCESS connection with PHP ODBC on CentOS

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc, freetds

I have a management software hosted on a Windows Server 2003 machine, this software using an MS Access (*.mdb) database.

On another machine, that work with CentOS 6.7 I installed all the necessary modules relative to php odbc, freetds, etc..

Now I need to connect to my remote db using this PHP code:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver=FreeTDS;Server=ip_of_windows_server;DBQ=mdb_file_name.mdb;Uid=;Pwd=my_mdb_password;");

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

The error I got is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source' in /home/my_user/public_html/odbc/index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /home/my_user/public_html/odbc/index.php(21): PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER=Fre...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/my_user/public_html/odbc/index.php on line 21
```

you can see that I don't use any username for my DB, but the same is if I type 'root' in the username.

The `Driver = FreeTDS` is taken from `etc/odbcinst.ini` with this content:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC PDO
Driver = /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Driver64 = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
UsageCount = 1
Threding = 2
```

and in `etc/odbc.ini` I have this content:

```
[mydb]
Description = "Microsoft Access Try DB"
Driver = FreeTDS
Database = /my_mdb_name.mdb
Servername = ip_of_windows_server
Port = 80
Trace = No
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

I'm sure that I wrong something, but I don't know what :P

Thanks in advance.

Comment: access is not a client/server system. there's no "server" to connect to. there's just the .mdb file itself, which you'd access as a file in a share. probably need `database = sharename/whatever.mdb` instead, so the full path would be `\\ip_of_windows_server\share\my_mdb_name.mdb`

Comment: I installed a webserver on the Windows machine and the root directory is the same dir where there is the database.mdb. I also tried your tip but the result is always the same. Have you got other suggestion?

Comment: `database=/my` would be a local file reference, then? that'd also be the ROOT of the filesystem, e.g. `c:\my_mdb_name.mdb`. you'd need the actual path to the file.